# Facing error messages when importing sklearn in python i.d

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip, package-managers

I get an error when importing sklearn in python 3.9.
I am using I.D.L.E. in Windows.
Installed it using cmd command: `pip install -U scikit-learn` as given in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

The received error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .fixes import parse_version, threadpool_info
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 19, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 453, in <module>
    from ._stats_py import *
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_py.py", line 38, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
    from ._qhull import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _qhull: The specified module could not be found.
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you looked into directory `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial` if there is a file named _qhull.*.DLL? That is, what the import is looking for and for some reason can not find/load. Which version of scipy have you installed (output of `python -m pip show scipy`)?

Comment: @Frank this is the output of your command:                                                                               Name: scipy
Version: 1.8.0
Summary: SciPy: Scientific Library for Python
Home-page: https://www.scipy.org
Author:
Author-email:
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy
Required-by: scikit-learn                                                                                                                         Please Help

Comment: @Frank apparently there are files named qhull.py,  _qhull.cp39-win_amd64.pyd  and _qhull.pyi  and also a folder named qhull_src. Please please help

Comment: Did you try the dependency walker to find out, what is missing on your computer to have the pyd-file load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my scipy got corrupted somehow. Uninstalling and re-installing it fixed the problem. Thanks everyone who took their time and effort to help though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the required file _qhull.yp39-win_amd64.pyd is there, it must be a problem with the dependencies this DLL file has and can't find on your computer.

Use a dependency walker like [this one](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to find out what is missing on your system and see that you get those missing pieces installed.

Quite likely you are missing some of the [Microsoft Redistributable Visual Studio Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).

Comment: I am sorry but, it is still not working for me. Please help